# Multiple symfony3 localized sites in different geographic TLD domains, sharing the same core

Tags: symfony, deployment, routes, localization, multilingual

## For the impatients

What should be the `routing.yml` strategy in a project that will deploy several locales in several domains, some of the locales being "similar", and for which the pages, logic and layouts are absolutely identical?

## Context

I have an agency travel. Let's name the public web "catalog". I'm currently having the catalog in Spanish (`es_ES`) in my `.es` domain with a Symfony 3 project.

I'll translate it into catalan (`ca_ES`) into my `.cat` domain. Next translations are going to be in English UK (`en_GB`) and Spanish Mexico (`es_MX`). In the next future, more "spanishes" and more "englishes" will be added, among others.

I currently have 5 main routes in my symfony (there are more, but for the question here, it is enough):

```
/                       # proposal of value, main message
/viajes                 # index of the catalog
/quienes-somos          # Who we are
/{destination}          # for example "/tailandia")
/{destination}/{trip}   # for example "/tailandia/circuito-norte-sur")
```

Note that `/viajes` and `quienes-somos` are placed before `/{destination}` for the matcher to catch them properly.

I plan to add about 20 languages or language-variations in the next year.

## Deploy strategy

I'm currently having a deployer. The project consists of about 10 `.git` repos, one for the admin panel, one for the catalog, one for the DDD model, one for the statics, etc.

## Domain strategy

- When a regional TLD domain is available, my plan is to get them:

  - http://example.es/
  - http://example.cat/
  - http://example.mx/
  - http://example.co.uk/ etc.
- When not available, I plan to make subdomains or a directory inside a special global domain:

  - http://it.globalexample.com/
  - http://jp.globalexample.com/
- or alternatively:

  - http://globalexample.com/it/
  - http://globalexample.com/jp/

## Static routes problems

I forecast spaghetti problems with the routing if I only use a single `.git` and a single `routing.yml`.

I don't see having just:

```
/qui-som        # For Catalan
/chi-siamo      # For Italian
/quienes-somos  # HEY!! WHAT HERE? es_ES or es_MX???
/who-we-are     # the same => en_US or en_GB?
```

They need "host" qualification.

## Dynamic routes problems

Also, when the route matches `/{destination}` or `/{destination}/{trip}` I want to explore only a subset of the destinations:

If I'm in `example.mx` and I get `/tailandia/circuito-sur-norte` I don't need to explore the full destination list in all the languages, and all the trips; only the Spanish `es_MX` seo-friendly destinations and trips.

Similarly, if I'm in `example.co.uk` and I get `/thailand/circuit-south-north` I need only to explore the `en_GB` seo-titles to get what to render.

## Strategies thought up to now

I have thought 2 strategies that could work:

### a) Routing YML strategy

In the `routing.yml` have some kind of "rule" related to the "host" and set the "_locale" param by hand, something similar to:

```
whoWeAre_es_ES:
    path: /quienes-somos
    methods: [ GET ]
    host: example.es
    defaults:
        _controller: CatalogBundle:Legal:whoWeAre
        _locale: es_ES

whoWeAre_es_MX:
    path: /quienes-somos
    methods: [ GET ]
    host: example.mx
    defaults:
        _controller: CatalogBundle:Legal:whoWeAre
        _locale: es_MX
```

NOTE/DOUBT: I don't know if that "host" thing there would actually affect the route matcher or it is only for building routes.

In addition, this creates a problem when generating the routes. If in the home page I'm placing a link to the `whoWeAre` I should be knowing what of those routes to render and yields me in some kind of spaghetti code which is undesired.

### b) Deployer strategy

Have multiple routing.yml files and tune the inclusion in the deployer:

```
src/CatalogBundle/Resources/config/routing_es_ES.yml
src/CatalogBundle/Resources/config/routing_es_MX.yml
src/CatalogBundle/Resources/config/routing_en_GB.yml
src/CatalogBundle/Resources/config/routing_en_US.yml
```

Then in the deployer, use a `sed` over the file

```
app/config/routing.yml
```

and include one or other of the routing files in function of the domain I am currently deploying.

I like this approach as each domain will have it's own "auto-contained" routing definition; and it also allows me to set the locale for the full site as a setting in the `config.yml` like this:

```
parameters:
    locale: en_GB
```

Instead, this creates ugly duplication. For example, all the general matching routes like `/{destination}/{trip}` will be duplicated in all the routing files.

Okey, I could extract them common factor to aother file which is included by all of them.

### Common problems to both approaches

Still the static routes only differentiate in setting the `_locale` thing but share the `_controller` part.

I don't know if it is possible for a route in symfony to add a `default` parameter and then forward the matcher to another named route, like for example:

```
whoWeAre_es_ES:
    path: /quienes-somos
    host: example.es
    defaults:
        _locale: es_ES
    someKindOfReroutingThingPointingTo: whoWeAre

whoWeAre_es_MX:
    path: /quienes-somos
    host: example.mx
    defaults:
        _locale: es_MX
    someKindOfReroutingThingPointingTo: whoWeAre

whoWeAre_en_GB:
    path: /who-we-are
    host: example.co.uk
    defaults:
        _locale: es_MX
    someKindOfReroutingThingPointingTo: whoWeAre

whoWeAre:
    methods: [ GET ]
    defaults:
        _controller: CatalogBundle:Legal:whoWeAre
```

## So... Questions

- Is any of those two solutions something that I should go for?
- Anyone has tried any of those and has a list of objective pros-cons?
- What's the best **documented** best-practice routing strategy for multi-domain localization of a SF3 application?
- Is it possible for a routing definition to add some parameters and then switch to another routing rule that has common things?

Thnkx!

Comment: You should take a look at the strategy used in the [MultisiteBundle](https://github.com/alexandresalome/multisite-bundle). I used this bundle as a starting point for a big multi localized project of mine. With this bundle you can also internationalize each localization with the preferred locales.

Comment: @Xavi Montero What did you do at the end ? I'm comfronted to the same situation and I would love to hear as to what was your final solution.

Comment: I've not released multi-language sites yet, but I still plan to do. I took a look to the mentioned MultisiteBundle but I felt at the first glance that it was not as clean-code as I wished, so I thought it was going to be harder to come to a final clean good solution. I am actively wishing to come to a solution. @db306 I don't know if there's any way here in StackOverflow for private-messaging, I don't think so, but we might get in contact to explore together to do not clutter here, and once we have a final solution, publish it here together. How could we get in touch?

Comment: Tried to contact you privately via your magazine.

Comment: Updated my profile as well.

Comment: hey you can dm me via @Dan_Borisov on twitter. I have found something for now which isn't bad at all but would definitively have a look together see what we can come up with.